# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.0.0

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to compile a google cast package for react-native and I'm getting the following error:

Any tip? Thanks!

```
  problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-cast'.
       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-google-cast:_debugCompile'.
          > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.0.0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing  google play services Google repository on your Android SDK tools! If you have it already installed, update it. That worked for me!